prevent nginx from dropping first slash on proxy pass uri
We are using nginx for proxying requests received at some.url.com to an application (eXist-db) on an internal server. For this, we must take the path after the request domain and pass it as uri based on a few "simple" rules.
This works in some cases, but not others. I will give the configuration first, then identify the use cases that work and those which don't, with expected results.
The configuration:

server {
        server_name     some.url.com www.some.url.com;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/some.url.com/access.log main;
        #access_log     syslog:server=192.168.19.51,facility=local5,tag=nginx,severity=notice main;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/some.url.com/error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Remote-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header nginx-request-uri $request_uri;
            proxy_pass http://172.16.0.4:8080/exist/apps/my_app/;
        }

        location /exist {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Remote-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header nginx-request-uri $request_uri;
            proxy_pass http://172.16.0.4:8080/exist;
        }

        location /resources/images {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Remote-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header nginx-request-uri $request_uri;
            proxy_pass http://172.16.0.4/images;
        }

        location /resources/files {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Remote-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header nginx-request-uri $request_uri;
            proxy_pass http://172.16.0.4/files;
        }



}

What does work:
location /resources/images and location /resources/files work fine to direct requests to some.url.com/resources/images and some.url.com/resources/files on a file server.
All other requests should be sent on to the eXist application server according to two rules.
Any requests starting with some.url.com/exist/ should be sent on with the uri. This is handled fine by location /exist , i.e. some.url.com/exist/apps/dashboard or some.url.com/exist/apps/monex
All other requests should be sent on to /exist/apps/my_app with the URI appended.
This works fine for requests to the base URL, either as some.url.com/ or some.url.com
What doesn't work:
The problem is with URLs like some.url.com/archives and some.url.com/documents. These are passed respectively as
/exist/apps/my_apparchives

/exist/apps/my_appdocuments

when they should be passed as
/exist/apps/my_app/archives

/exist/apps/my_app/documents

Evidently the first slash after the domain is being deleted when it needs to be passed in the URI.
Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

The configuration in your question looks correct. The problem you describe would happen if the proxy_pass statement was missing the final /. Use nginx -T (uppercase T) to view the entire configuration across all included files, and check that it matches the snippet in your question. Have you restarted Nginx since making any configuration changes?

@RichardSmith We restarted nginx to no immediate effect. 3 hours later I happened to try...and now it works. It seems a restart is not entirely fool proof. I have to work through sys admin, so perhaps there is more going on at server level in caching than what I see while working on my vm.
